# PhpStorm does not recognize Doctrine's default entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm

I have the following code :

```
$repo = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')
    ->getRepository('Acme:Foo');
```

For the record, the code is working correctly since I can use `$repo`, its methods and the resulting entities without a problem.

However PhpStorm highlights the `'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'` string and gives me the following error:

> Missing service

I get the same error in my services files when referencing that particular service. Following that, obviously, autocomplete does not work. I can use the following workaround, of course:

```
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em */
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
$em->getRepository('Acme:Foo');
```

This way I still get a warning but autocompletion works properly. However, I'd rather keep my code clean from this kind of annotation as much as possible, plus I'm almost sure there's an easy fix for that. I have of course cleared my cache multiple times.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I need to mention I'm using the Symfony2 plugin.

Comment: Have you installed the Symfony plugin for PhpStorm (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219)?

Comment: @ThierryMarianne : yes I do have the plugin installed and at the latest version. I'll update my question to mention it, thank you.

Comment: This is a silly question but, is the symfony plugin enabled? Happened to me a while ago :D, you can check in `"Settings > Languages & Fra.. > PHP > Symfony"`

Answer (score 4):

In PhpStorm i accidentally mark directory "var" as "Excluded"
So my "fix" was easy:
right click on directory, "Mark Directory as" -> "Cancel Exclusion"

Answer (score 2):

Using latest stable PHPStorm and Symfony plugin, I had problem with some services because my `var/cache/` was in `/dev/shm` in my vagrant box (while PHPStorm is running on windows).

When I have all files `var/cache` it should be working well.

I think that it needs `var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml` to be generated, up to date, and accessible.

Comment: This is my problem as well. Within my vagrant box I am storing the cache locally so as to avoid overhead of the network. Doing this increases performance notably, but has the side effect of PHPStorm being unable to see the files in there to know about some produced services.

Comment: During my build process, I've added a step that copies the cache from the "fast folder" to the "standard var/cache folder"

Answer (score 0):

We did the following to avoid issues like you're describing:

In our **services.yml** I have defined:

```
    entity_manager:
        alias: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

The problem was that obviously the Symfony 2 plugin doesn't recognize some 'standard' services which are usually available.

And now using

```
$this->get('entity_manager');
```

isn't showing any issue with an activated Symfony 2 plugin.

We use a very similar approach for other *'general services'* like Logger, Mailer etc.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments. Check in `Settings -> Plugins` Search **Symfony Plugin**
Then Install it.
[image]